# Confused about passing data frame between functions with RStudio's Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like two plots to appear. First, a scatter plot and then a line graph. The graphs aren't important. This is my first time using Shiny. What is the best way to have both

```
  plotOutput("needles"),
  plotOutput("plot")
```

use the data from the same needles data frame? I think I'm getting confused as to how to pass the "needles" data frame between the plotOutput functions.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

# Create the data frame ________________________________________________
create_data <- function(num_drops) {
  needles <- tibble (
    x = runif(num_drops, min = 0, max = 10),
    y = runif(num_drops, min = 0, max = 10)
  )
}

# Show needles ________________________________________________
show_needles <- function(needles) {
 ggplot(data = needles, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
    geom_point()

}

# Show plot __________________________________________________
show_plot <- function(needles) {
  ggplot(data = needles, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
    geom_line()
}

# Create UI
ui <- fluidPage(

  sliderInput(inputId = "num_drops", 
              label = "Number of needle drops:",
              value = 2, min = 2, max = 10, step = 1),

  plotOutput("needles"),
  plotOutput("plot")

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$needles <- renderPlot({
    needles <- create_data(input$num_drops)
    show_needles(needles)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    show_plot(needles)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could execute the `create_data` inside a `reactive` call in the `server` and then within the `renderPlot`, pass the value (`needles()`) as arguments for `show_needles` and `show_plot`

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  needles <- reactive({
     create_data(input$num_drops)

  })
  output$needles <- renderPlot({

    show_needles(needles())
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    show_plot(needles())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thank-you for your help.